# Tree hierarchy data [users => session => results]

Tags: ios, hierarchical-data

Still new to xcode, please excuse any errors or misunderstanding, i hope being the clearest possible

I have a user list containing some usernames (user1, user2, user3...). I saved this list in a NSMutableArray that i get by NSUserDefaults.

**Now, in my app, each user is going to create his own one or several sessions.
And each session will save one or several results.**

I can't post any image so this is a simple way to represent what i want :

> ```
>      user1
> ```
>
> session 1              session 2
>
> result1 (session1)       //       result1 (session2)
>
> > result2(session1)        //       result2(session2)
> >
> > > result3 (session1)

I tried to find out some methods or something like that but maybe my key words are not enough pertinent.
What will be the best solution to do that ?

I was thinking using a NSMutableArray saving all the session for each user in a NSUserDefaults with objectForKey the name of the user (and the same thing for the results except setting objectForkey the name of the session) but i think it is gonna be very tough and long...

Thank you guys !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any sort of complex data with relationships you should move on to using CoreData. NSUserDefaults really excels when having simple key-value pairs, but nothing more.

It's a bit of a learning curve to get into it, but once it's set up, you'll understand why it's better to go this way.

[CoreData Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

Comment: Thanks ! It was hard for me but i did it !! :)

Comment: @user3658292 If you got it working within a day, you've done well :)